# Can I change my trainer name?

Tags: pokemon-go

I picked a name I regret in Pokemon Go, and wish I could change it. I've heard you might need to contact support.

Is there a way to change your trainer name in Pokemon Go, or do I need to make a new account?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes! Beginning with the August 8th update, you can change your name **once**.

Remember it must be [**between 4 and 15 characters long**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281004/how-short-or-long-can-my-trainer-name-be).

[image]

[image]

[image]