# Will I be warned before changing my trainer name?

Tags: pokemon-go

I would like to explore available trainer names, since we can now [change our name once](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/280816/125786).

I'm wondering if when you enter a name, if it automatically changes your name or does it give you a confirmation it's available (or not) first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change your name from the settings menu it will ask you *twice*, whether or not you want to be renamed. 

*After* confirming both questions it will check for availability. So yes... the procedure is pretty much the same. If it's available you get it right away with no further confirmation request.

Comment: @Insane it turns out the latest update changed this a bit. Editing.

Comment: Oh. My question is specific to after the update. I'm talking about using the [name change dialog from settings](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/280816/125786). Same behavior? If you can confirm the behavior is the same I'll re accept.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll get my test account.

Comment: @Insane done. Its pretty much the same. You will only get asked before it actually checks for availability.

Comment: Cool. You may want to restructure your answer since the question was only asking about changing names not picking a name initially. You kinda have to read a lot of unnecessary info to get to the bottom part. Thanks for testing :-)