# How short or long can my trainer name be?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm trying to think of my new trainer name but I [don't get any chance to check if the username is available](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/280835/will-i-be-warned-before-changing-my-trainer-name) before trying it.

What I'm wondering is what the minimum and maximum characters are for your trainer name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some brief experimentation, I've discovered that your new proposed trainer name must be between 4-15 characters. It can only contain letters and numbers (no special characters or spaces).

In addition, if you try to change your trainer name to one that is already taken, the game will flash an error message saying `That name isn't available`, so it's okay to try a bunch of different trainer names to find one that is available.

Comment: Perfect. I didn't think 4 character usernames were available but I'm glad the are!

Comment: @Insane Wait, that range was supposed to be (3,15], so actually 4-15 characters. My mistake